# Device-specific Google Contacts password without 2-step verification

Tags: google-calendar, google-account, security, google-contacts

I'm setting up a new phone to synchronize with my Google Contacts, Calendar and maybe Mail.

However, I feel very uncomfortable entering my central Google password into the phone. What happens if it's stolen? I would like a separate password that I can enter into the phone.

However, the only way I can do this seems to be by activating 2-step verification, something I do not want to do because I often travel without my phone.

Is there any way for me to get a  separate password to use on my phone?

Comment: Why not add a password to access the phone itself?

Comment: @Al I already have that, but I still don't like the idea of my master password hanging around somewhere on the phone. On the other hand, if it gets stolen, I'll just change the password... Plus  I just found out that there are backup codes for 2-step verification, so I may be able to use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have two different passwords for the same account. What you can do is either:

1. Have a password to access the phone itself (as Al suggested); or
2. Have a second account set on the phone, that has access (through sharing) to your main account calendar and contacts (I'm not sure how this works or even if it does, to be honest); or
3. Have some VPN client on the phone, that gives you access to your home computer.

Yes, these are very looooong shots, but what you are asking for is not that simple (or even possible, for that matter).

**Edit:**

What you can also do is setup the two-step verification, indeed. This way, you will have a special app password that allows it to connect to your account.

> After you turn on 2-step verification, non-browser applications and devices that use your Google Account (such as the Gmail app on your phone or Outlook), will be unable to connect to your account. However, in a few steps, you can generate a *special password called application-specific password* to allow this application to connect to your account -- and don't worry, you'll only have to do this once for each device or application.

From [this Accounts help page](http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/static.py?hl=en&page=guide.cs&guide=1056283&answer=1085463&rd=3) (emphasis by me).

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I opted for using 2-step verification in the end because there still are ways to access your account without your mobile phone. With 2-step verification, it *is* actually possible to have two (or more) different passwords for the same account. If you add that information to your answer, I'll accept it :)

Comment: @Pekka See the edit. I added some details regarding the 2-step verification.

Answer (score 0):

You can now activate [two step verification](https://www.google.com/landing/2step/) for your Google Account. Then set an *[app specific password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=no)* for each application that you want.